# AWS API Gateway call api in private VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a service deployed on an ec2 in private subnet and privateSG. I am able to access this service from EC2 in public subnet and publicSG. I want to create an API Gateway which would expose this api to my clients[Mobile App].

What is the way to achive this?

I have created and API Gateway, resource and method, but this the api call not reaching the service on ec2. below is the error

````
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Starting execution for request: c7290ccc-5859-44cf-bta2-90ff498cdec6
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : HTTP Method: GET, Resource Path: /item/item-1
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Method request path: {id=item-1}
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Method request query string: {}
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Method request headers: {}
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Method request body before transformations: 
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Execution failed due to configuration error: Invalid endpoint address
Wed Feb 17 10:14:38 UTC 2021 : Method completed with status: 500```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable your API Gateway access your private instance you can setup [API Gateway private integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-private-integration.html):

> The API Gateway private integration makes it simple to **expose your HTTP/HTTPS resources within an Amazon VPC** for access by clients outside of the VPC.

The alternative way is to use a [lambda function integrated with your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html) as a proxy. So your API would invoke the function, the function in turn would invoke your API on the private instance and return answer to the API.